# Как можно получить IP сервера Minecraft через Java?

Tags: java, сервер, ip, плагин, minecraft

У меня есть хак-плагин Minecraft, который я пишу. Я делаю админ-панель на минималках через сайт. Но я делаю продвинутую админ-панель.

1. Моим плагином могут пользоваться 2+ человека
2. Следовательно, 1 человек - 1 сервер
3. Мне нужно выполнить команду от лица консоли на **определенный сервер!**

Вопрос: как мне это сделать?
Жду ответы, надеюсь на верный ответ <3

Comment: И что вызвало затруднения?

Comment: Затруднения в том, что нужно чтобы плагин выполнял команду именно на сервер, айпишник которого ввел пользователь

Comment: и как мне тогда получить ip серверов на которых есть плагин?

Comment: Если пользователь вводит IP адрес, то в чем проблема послать команду по этому адресу?

Comment: Как это сделать? Я просто не знаю...

Comment: Погугли про rcon